# typeerror when reading state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to use zebra to set a state to a json, which is produced by zebras reading a csv in the class constructor.

```
import "./Maps.css";
import * as z from "zebras";
import df3 from "./df3.json"

class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = z.readCSV(df3);
    this.state = data
}

  render()
  {
    console.log(this.state)

    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Maps
```

Im getting the following error, when trying to console log the state (i have converted csv to json and imported file into js)

```
TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readFileSync is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (readCSV.js:18)
    at Module.f1 (_curry1.js:16)
    at new Maps (Maps.js:9)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12905)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17040)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18510)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23028)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22019)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:21992)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21610)
    at react-dom.development.js:11130
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:656)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11076)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11125)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11113)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21053)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24191)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24590)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24656)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (index.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: zebras is a library for nodeJS, not in-browser JavaScript.

Comment: thank you so much. Do you have any recommendations for setting state with csvs?

Comment: @VP9 you might need to use webpack plugin to import csv directly to react or convert csv to json file and simply `import file from './file.json'`.

Comment: Move the file over into your project's `public` folder, then request it with `fetch()`.

Comment: i converted file to json and imported directly, not sure what the problem could be

Comment: @VP9 how didyou converted? which tool did you used?

Comment: After converting to json you dont need to use zebras since csv file will be already parsed

Comment: The problem is you're *still* trying to use a server-side library in a client-side script. Remove all references to `zebras`, then start with a `console.log(df3);` in your constructor and check the output.

Comment: thank you, done and it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to import a json file (as I see in your code), You just need to fetch the file:

```
fetch('./data.json').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      // Work with JSON data here
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      // Do something for an error here
      console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
    });
```

and then update your state after you fetch it.
Hope this can fix the error.